# MockMvc fails because of method invocation inside the controller method

Tags: mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test, hittest, mockmvc

I try to mock a controller which contains a util method inside even though I mock the util method, the mvcMock ignore the result from the when(...) and call the method again with empty parameters which lead to nullpointerexception

How I can ship the call of

```
when(utilMock.getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, adNames)).thenReturn(roleSet);
```

with the mockMvc.perform?

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/wellbore"})
public String wellboreForm(Model model, @RequestParam("mode") String mode, HttpServletRequest request) {

    Set<String> operators = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    String userName = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("userName");
    Set<String> operatorsSet = (HashSet<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("userRoles");


    Set<String> operatorsAdName = util.getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, operatorsSet);
    operatorsAdName.forEach(adName -> {
        Query query = new Query()
                .setClassname(Wellbore.CLASS)
                .eq(Wellbore.operatorsGroup, adName);
        operators.addAll(getWellboresNameList(query));
    });

        model.addAttribute("wellboreDataList", operators);
        model.addAttribute("wellboreData", new WellboreForm());

        return "ui/selectWellbore";
}



 public static Set<String> getOperatorsAdName(String userName, Set<String> operatorsAdName) {
    operatorsAdName.removeIf(x -> x.equals(userName)
            || x.equals("SCOUT")
            || x.equals("GTO")
            || x.equals("KADME")
            || x.equals("offline_access")
            || x.equals("uma_authorization"));

    return operatorsAdName;
}

public Set<String> getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(String userName, Set<String> operatorsAdName) {
    return getOperatorsAdName(userName,operatorsAdName);
}


@Mock
private Util utilMock;

@Test
@DisplayName("GET /wellbore - Select Wellbore")
void testMockMvc() throws Exception {


    HttpServletRequest req = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    when(req.getAttribute("userName")).thenReturn("abcd");

    String userName = (String) req.getAttribute("userName");

    //Here I get the correct result Result 
    when(utilMock.getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, adNames)).thenReturn(roleSet); 

    //another call made here with empy parameters to utilMock.getOperatorsAdNameWrapper("", null)
    mockMvc.perform(get("/wellbore").param("mode","selectWellbore")
            .sessionAttr("wellboreDataList", new LinkedHashSet<>())
            .sessionAttr("wellboreData", new WellboreForm())
    )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("ui/selectWellbore"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("wellboreDataList", hasSize(2)));
}
```

Comment: where is getOperatorsAdNameWrapper method used in the SUT?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Hi it is called inside the controller
 I fixed the typo in the controller but as I said the method called with empty parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with the **Util** class 
since I am using mockmvc as unit testing, not as integration test by ***standaloneSetup***

```
 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            //To avoid loading springContext
            .standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setViewResolvers(viewResolver())
            .build();
```

so the Util class not loaded to the context to solve this you have to option

1. Move the wrapper method in the util class to the service class and from there you can wrapper the static method in the Util class
2. Add the util class to the controller constructor

Answer (score 1):

**1)** In the Controller move the line:

```
util.getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, operatorsSet);
```

into a package level method:

```
Set<String> getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, operatorsSet){
   return util.getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, operatorsSet); 
}
```

**2)** In your test use `SpyBean`:

```
@SpyBean
private Controller controllerSpy;

@Test
@DisplayName("GET /wellbore - Select Wellbore")
void testMockMvc() throws Exception {

   doReturn(roleSet).when(controllerSpy).getOperatorsAdNameWrapper(userName, adNames);
```

The general gist is that you cannot mock a static call with vanilla Mockito. You have to refactor a bit first.

Comment: Hi @Maciej Kowalski Thanks for your answer
yes, I know the gist is to avoid the static method that is why I invocate it via the wrapper method 
I followed what you suggested but the mockmvc still ignore the return type from the when(....) can make a new call to the getOperatorsAdNameWrapper with empty parameters